# Hibernate: Change the loaded entity after properties have been injected

Tags: java, hibernate

After loading an entity (via load or find), just before the response is returned, i'd like to change the entity (the actual reference). Does anyone know how to do this?
The reason is that the entity into which the properties were injected during load is a builder object.
I tried to use a PostLoadEventListener like this:

```
public void onPostLoad(PostLoadEvent event) {
  Object entity = event.getEntity();
  if(null != entity && entity instanceof MyBuilder){
    MyBuilder builder = (MyBuilder)entity;
    MyActualClass result = builder.build();
    event.setEntity(result);
  }
}
```

but it seems that whatever I set in that event is ignored and lost (makes sense, this is how events work).
The only option that seems to be left is overriding an EntityPersister but that's so yucky! 
Do you know of another, more elegant solution?
Thanks!
Cristian

Comment: Are you doing this because you want your entity to be read-only?

Comment: @JeremyHeiler Yes the objects are meant to be immutable and have no setters. The think is, I don't know how will this affect the Hibernate cache. I save an objects and when I try to get it from database I get a builder object.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement the Hibernate's EmptyIntercepter and provide the implementation for onLoad method where you can do whatever you want immediately after loading from the database and before sending the response.

you can get more info on this here http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html

Comment: I considered that, but look at the method signature: `boolean onLoad(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types)`. You return boolean not an entity. And because in Java parameters are transmitted by reference copy I can't change the entity.

Comment: you can change in this method and store in the cache so that you can get it whenever you want.

Comment: So I looked into it, but it seems quite weird to use a cache to pass the results around. I think i'll rather wrap the session into a transformer.

Comment: hey, without cache and without returning anything, atleast you can change the entity in this method. as it by reference, you can see the changes outside method as well.

Comment: Yep. I know the situation is weird. Don't get me wrong. Passing the object through a cache is an innovative solution. I might end up using it. I just still have doubts that it doesn't mess up with hibernate's internal workings.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to make a read-only entity, then you can make all your setters `protected` and Hibernate will use reflection to initially set them. Then in your application the object will effectively be immutable.

Hibernate also allows [entities to be read-only](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/readonly.html), but not necesarily immutable in the java sense.

Comment: Hey Jeremy. Thanks for sticking with me for this. The objects are not immutable in that sense. They change over time, but in Java each time you do this you create a new one and destroy the old one. In Hibernate this would be overkill, especially because the id doesn't change. Regarding setters, unfortunately this is not possible. The objects I'm trying to persist are [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) and are cread by a generator outside my control. They simply don't have setters. I know the situation is very weird. That's why there's no support for such things.

Comment: @Cristain: Very interesting. Let us know what you end up doing!